# Spark codegen error when perform count distinct with groupingsets

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark sql perforce count distinct with groupingsets,likt

```
select
a,
b,
c,
count(distinct d) as d,
count(distinct e) as e
from
table
where
a=x
group by
a,b,c
groupingsets
((a),(ab),(ac),(abc))
```

But sometimes the job will get an exception

```
17/08/04 10:35:31 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 21 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 21.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 1261, rz-data-hdp-dn0158.rz.sankuai.com, executor 124): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$2.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:396)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't get any useful information from this exception.

The spark version I used is 2.1

Is it a spark's bug? Or is there anything I need to modify?

Comment: You have missed a comma between `count(distinct d) as d` and 
`count(distinct e) as e`. This may not be a reason but it's an obvious bug in your SQL.

Comment: Sorry, it a slip of the pen. It's not the reason. I changed the spark version from 2.1 to 2.2, and it seems solved.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19037

Comment: @lulijun Please post it as an answer and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the spark version from 2.1 to 2.2, and the problem solved.
It seems like a bug fixed in the 2.1.1 release and after
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19037